# python как обьединить два dataframe по полю datetime (при совпадении дня/месяца/года)

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

```
import pandas as pd


df_H4['time'].dt.day   # день ...
df_H4['time'].dt.month
df_H4['time'].dt.year

df_H4_union = pd.merge(df_H4, df_daily, how='left', left_on='time', right_on='time')
```

### Есть такие два dataframe: Тип поля time: datetime, trend: str/object

### df_H4:

| time | trend_H4 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-18 16:00:00 | down |
| 2022-02-18 20:00:00 | down |

### df_dayli:

| time | trend_day |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 | down |
| 2022-02-18 | up |

Как корретно их обьединить (левое соединение) по ключю 'time', при совпадении дня/месяца/года?
Условно:

```
df_H4['time'].dt.day = df_dayli['time'].dt.day
df_H4['time'].dt.month = df_dayli['time'].dt.day
...
```

### df_result: результат должен быть такой

| time | trend_H4 | trend_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-18 16:00:00 | down | up |
| 2022-02-18 20:00:00 | down | up |

Comment: можно заморочится/попробовать и создать новые поля содержващие соответсвенно дату, месяц и год и с помошью их мёржить

Comment: Да достаточно дату целиком (без времени) выделить в отдельное поле `date` и потом по нему `left join` делать: `df_H4['date'] = df_H4['time'].dt.date`

Comment: Спасибо Вам :) Мил человек

Comment: Пожалуй, вынесу в виде ответа тогда )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно дату целиком (без времени) выделить в отдельное поле:

```py
df_H4['date'] = df_H4['time'].dt.date
```